# add to cart with custom price attribute in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2

I need to add to cart products with custom attribute price

Ex i am having a custom price as booking amount as 1000 for a product and original amount as 10000

when customer chooses booking amount option 1000 should be added to cart and if user chooses full payment 10000 should be added to cart ..

How to acheive this in magento

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using product options. It could allow you to have 2 different options for your product with a different price for each options without having to do something out of the box.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/settings-advanced-custom-options.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :- It can be helpful for you to update price in cart.

Obviously, you create your action(Controller) class for booking button so add below code in your controller.

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Controller;

class ActionController extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $urlInterface;

    /**
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute() {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $params = $this->request->getParams(); // send product_id in request and here get it
        if (isset($params['product_id']) && $params['product_id']) {
            $customPrice = 1000;
            $params = [
                         'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                         'product' => $params['product_id'],             
                         'qty'   => $params['qty'] // 1,2,3
                 ];
        
            /* Load the product based on productID */  
            $_product = $this->product->load($params['product_id']);
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
            /* get quote items */
            $items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
            foreach($items as $item) {
                if ($item->getProductId() && $item->getProductId() == $params['product_id']) {
                    $item->setCustomPrice(round($customPrice,2));
                    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice(round($customPrice,2));
                    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                }
            }
            $this->cart->save();
    
            $resultRedirect->setPath($this->urlInterface->getUrl('checkout/cart', array('_secure' => true)));
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
}
```

`Thank You!`